# Обновления записи asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Model Order:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Text { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Payment { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Check(int id)
    {
    var model = await _context.Orders
                    .Include(b => b.User)
                    .Include(b => b.Service)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

            return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
          public async Task<IActionResult> Check([Bind("Subject", "Text")] Order order)
                {
                        _context.Update(order);

                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
```

View:

```
@model ... .Models.Order
<form asp-action="Check">
<input asp-for="Subject">
<input asp-for="Text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Так вот, мне нужно сделать обновления записи. И у меня выдает ошибку:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Payment', table
>   'Ad.dbo.Orders'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

В поле payment есть значение по умолчанию, его обновлять не надо. 
То есть ef воспринимает, как добавление записи, а не обновление.

Подскажите как исправить ошибку. Я бы хотел что-то наподобии автозаполнение сделать(mass assigning) сделать, то есть только те которые в `asp-for` вписаны будут обновляться, ибо полей много.

Comment: "В поле payment есть значение по умолчанию, его обновлять не надо." - и где оно? Пока я вижу, что Payment нет ни в форме ввода, ни в контролере ему не назначается какое-то удобоваримое значение, ни в самом классе Order этому свойству тож ничего не назначено. Оно пусто, а потому "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Payment'"

Comment: @Bulson в базе данных, ведь запись есть. Контекст получает данные, и отображает

Comment: Тогда в форме ввода добавьте скрытое поле для сохранения значения свойства Payment. Проверьте себя сейчас. Поставьте точку останова на вход в метод Check() и проверьте какая модель вернулась из формы ввода. Что лежит в свойстве Payment?

Comment: Да, действительно, спасибо. Это получается все так свойство надо скрывать, которые не требуется изменять? То посмотрел, другие свойство null получили

Comment: Именно так, иначе значения просто теряются.

Comment: И на будущее. Активнее используйте точки останова и проверку значений переменных, очень помогает самостоятельно находить причины ошибок.

Comment: На русском языке ничего приличного я не нашел, посмотрите этот [ролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-HdLtqEOog) очень доходчиво показывает и рассказывает, но, правда, на английском.

Comment: @Bulson хорошо, спасибо